# What events are for content change of text area element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple text area element which is initially empty or filled by some text :

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="10" id="textareaEdit" >some text</textarea>
```

I would like to know what events to use so whenever users change the text content of the textarea element (like copy/paste, delete, insert, update, and so on), corresponding event handlers will be triggered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements.` as stated in http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('copy paste cut change', 'textarea', function (e) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you.I have a question: what is the purpose of $('body') from beginning?

Comment: You welcome)
it means that you are attaching event handlers (copy,paste,cut...) to the body element